# Excel Vba Refreshing PivotTables , They disapear from report connections

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

i'm new in VBA and i'm trying to refresh the ranges  all pivot tables in a given sheet 
this is the piece of code i'm using

```
    For Each pvtbl In DashboardSheet.PivotTables
       'change the Ranges
       DashboardSheet.PivotTables(pvtbl.Name).ChangePivotCache 
       ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
       (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=NewRangeName)
    Next
```

This works great but unfortunately having 2 issues

1- if i try and add a slicer i can't see the report connections to link the slicer to all pivots ( all pivots have the same source range)
2- if i have a slicer already in place this code doesn't work

one of the errors i get is  when i open the file and try to filter 
"the pivot table report was saved without underlying data"
thank you very much for your help , since I've researched on the internet but can't really understand what i'm doing wrong